# Please help me to debug this. I can't figure out the error in code from LogCat

Tags: android

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/tv_location"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/tv_location"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

02-10 18:15:59.429: I/Process(439): Sending signal. PID: 439 SIG: 9
    02-10 18:16:26.105: D/AndroidRuntime(472): Shutting down VM
    02-10 18:16:26.105: W/dalvikvm(472): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/A
    ndroidRuntime(472): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.becram.maps/com.becram.maps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class Fragment
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class Fragment
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at com.becram.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  ... 11 more
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.becram.maps-1.apk]
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
    02-10 18:16:26.155: E/AndroidRuntime(472):  ... 20 more
    02-10 18:17:49.095: D/AndroidRuntime(507): Shutting down VM
    02-10 18:17:49.095: W/dalvikvm(507): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.becram.maps/com.becram.maps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class Fragment
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class Fragment
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at com.becram.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  ... 11 more
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.becram.maps-2.apk]
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
    02-10 18:17:49.195: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  ... 20 more
    02-10 18:17:59.835: I/Process(507): Sending signal. PID: 507 SIG: 9

Comment: Please post your XML file for `MainActivity`.

Comment: android.view.Fragment is not found

Comment: What is the OS version of the device you're using?

Comment: Are you on an API level 10 or lower device?

Comment: @gunar i am using API 10 in AVD in WIndows 8

Comment: @Paul-Jan i am on API 10

Answer (score 2):

If you need to support pre-Honeycomb devices use Fragments from [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

- all Activities that use support Fragment must extend FragmentActivity
- all Fragments must extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment